# Why can't I find a class in the DOM when using ui-bootstrap $modal?

Tags: angularjs, dom, angular-bootstrap

This question is more theoretical than practical but I have to ask it as a friend had a similar problem and I couldn't answer this for him.

I have a modal window that I use my extending the `$modal` object from AngularJS ui-bootstrap. Now when I open a modal I want to check if a class is present in the DOM (for no real reason, but I want to know if it is there). The class is determined in the service I created using $modal (see the options object). When I try and find the class using `document.querySelectorAll('.photo-modal').length;`  I return a zero however I can see the class in the DOM when using Chrome Dev tools and the class is applied. My friends problem was similar but they could find the class originally but after closing the Modal window they would return a null or zero value. Look at this example. I open a modal window and set a 'window-class' property. The class is there but JavaScript cannot find it. I have tried using `$timeout`, a DOM traverse function but nothing returns the existence of my class in the DOM. Look at this example and notice the console.

```js
angular.module('modalStuff', ['ui.bootstrap'])

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'ModalService', function ($scope, ModalService) {

   $scope.openModal = function () {
   ModalService.profilePic();
   };
}])

.factory('ModalService', ['$modal', function ($modal) {

var modal = angular.copy($modal);

   modal.profilePic = function ( ) {

   var options = {
      template:'<div silly-directive>Content of the template.</div>',
   windowClass: 'photo-modal'
   };

   return modal.open(options);
};
   
   return modal;
   
}])

.directive('sillyDirective', [function () {
  
  var findUpDom = function (elem, cssClassName) {

    if (elem.classList.contains(cssClassName)) {
     return elem;
    } else {
     while (elem.parentNode) {
      elem = elem.parentNode;
      if (elem && elem.classList.contains(cssClassName)) {
       return true;
      }
     }
     return false;
    }

   };
  
   
  return { 
    link: function (scope, element) {
     
      var myClass= document.querySelectorAll('.my-class').length;
      var modalClass= document.querySelectorAll('.photo-modal').length;     
      
      console.log(myClass, modalClass);      
      //console.log(findUpDom(element[0],'photo-modal')); // Returns an error as undefined
    }
  
  };
   
}]
);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.photo-modal {
  background-color: blue;
}

.my-class {
  background-color: lightBlue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body data-ng-app="modalStuff" data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="my-class">
    <button data-ng-click="openModal()">Open Me</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Now can anyone explain to me why the css class cannot be found? I also have the example here in a JSBin: https://jsbin.com/nuxipo/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Works fine with very small delay or using `$timeout`. Your directive is likely being compiled before the class is added

Comment: https://jsbin.com/faqakasowe/edit?js,console,output